# sql reporting services deployment

Tags: sql, sql-server, deployment, reporting-services

I am a beginner user of SQL Reporting Services. I wrote a few reports. They all use stored procedures on my development SQL server. Now I want to deploy them into production, and repoint the datasets and datasources to my production SQL db.

How best to do this? Can I just do a global change from development_server_name to production_server_name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set up your reports to use a shared data source. The data source is published along with the reports. You deploy your datasource, then go into SSRS management URL and modify the newly deployed data source to point to a the production server. All subsequent deployments will preserve this change, so you can now deploy modified and new reports at leisure, they will automatically pick up the redirect to the production server once they are on the SSRS site.

Of course, if you used stored procedures, you need to deploy those as well on the production server.

If you didn't used shared data sources on the reports, then lear your lesson, go back and change them to use a shared data source, then deploy.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The sprocs were already deployed.  I did use a shared data source but I am having some difficulty following your instructions. When I try to run a report (for which I have updated the datasource) I get an error message referencing the original server name which says "The datasource cannot be found"

Comment: Perhaps some datatsets don't use the shared data source, or the shared data source is not properly modified. You should use the techniques described here to get more detaisl on errors: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd353298(SQL.90).aspx